# How to recreate animation as in "PATH android app " in their user profile page?

Tags: android, drag, android-animation

In path application the user can drag the profile info down to reveal the image of the user . 
I need same animation in our app . Can anyone guide me how to create this animation in android ?

I am talking about animation in http://cl.ly/MBQh

Thanks

Comment: No chance of posting a video of this effect?

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: youtube link of that animation would be more easy  to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd basically have two views, the one that user can drag, and the one hiding underneath, both of them children of a `RelativeLayout`.

The tricky part is the dragging/animation of the top view. Please, take this snippet as an example I wrote a time ago for a similar effect in x axis. Notice this logic is inside an extended `View`.-

```
final RelativeLayout wrapperDraggable = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewWrapperDraggable);
wrapperDraggable.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                initPoint = new Point((int) event.getRawX(), (int) event.getRawY());
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // Disable parent scrolling if user is dragging the view
                if (dragging || Math.abs(initPoint.x - event.getRawX()) > Math.abs(initPoint.y - event.getRawY()) * 2) {
                    dragging = true;                          
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                } else {                                    
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                }

                int offset = (int) Math.max(Math.min(0, event.getRawX() - initPoint.x), -CurrentViewClass.this.getWidth() * 0.45f);

                if (offset != lastOffset) {
                    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(lastOffset, offset, 0, 0);
                    anim.setFillAfter(true);
                    anim.setFillEnabled(true);
                    anim.setDuration(0);                                         
                    wrapperDraggable.startAnimation(anim);

                    lastOffset = offset;
                }
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (!dragging) {
                    // The user clicked the view
                }
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                dragging = false;
                TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(lastOffset, 0, 0, 0);
                anim.setFillAfter(true);
                anim.setDuration(300);
                wrapperDraggable.startAnimation(anim);
                lastOffset = 0;
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

i think that you need to look at the [PullToRefresh Library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh).
Here you can configure your HeaderView of ListView. and It will appear then you pull down.
Also if you pull enough you cause event to be done.